# how to resolve null pointer exception while retrieving files in service class?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, difference

The file utils which i am using in my service class is not retrieving the files from its path,but when i am using the same in activity its performing as required.
so can anyone suggest me the correct answer for my question.

These are my programming lines which i have used.

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    IBinder mBinder;
    private File root;
    private ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/user/");
        getfile(root);
        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++)
        {
            if (fileList.get(i).isDirectory()) {
                File userPath = new File(fileList.get(i).getPath());

                File[] uFiles = userPath.listFiles();
                for (int k = 0; k < uFiles.length; k++) {
                    File f1 = new File(uFiles[k].toString());
                    String comFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/" + uFiles[k].getName();
                    // System.out.println(comFile);
                    // System.out.println(f1.getPath());
                    File f2 = new File(comFile);
                    try {
                        boolean compare1and2 = FileUtils.contentEquals(f1, f2);
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Are " + uFiles[k] + " and " + comFile + " the same? " + compare1and2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (!compare1and2) {
                            File f4 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/upload/" + uFiles[k].getName());
                            File f3 = new File(comFile);
                            FileUtils.copyFile(f3, f4);
                            f1.delete();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File uploaded" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            System.out.println("file uploaded");
                        } else {
                            f1.delete();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                fileList.get(i).delete();
            }

        }
    }
    public ArrayList<File> getfile (File dir)
    {
        Log.e("logger", dir.toString());

        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                    getfile(listFile[i]);

                } else {
                    if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".png")
                            || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")
                            || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpeg")
                            || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".gif"))

                    {
                        fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return fileList;

    }
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"  onbind", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return  mBinder;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please share the logcat

Comment: 'so can anyone suggest me the correct answer for my question.' What is your question? And in the subject you suggest thst your post is about a null pointer exception but you don't even name it. Or telling which statement causes it.

Comment: @Hema share logcat first.

Answer (score 0):

> Null Pointer Exception

This is a generic issue as the `instance` of the `class` is not initiated, you are getting this `error`.

when you are using third party `library` and you are not sure how it may behave with certain `methods`, you should always check if the given `instance` generated by that `method` is null or not, before taking any action on that `reference variable` as that `method` may have returned `null`

In your code put conditions like this

```
if(object != null){
 // now you can call methods on this reference variable as it is not null
}else{
  // forget it, the reference variable, does not hold address to any object, if you try anything with this, VM will complain with Null Pointer Exception 
}
```

I would recommend you to check this `variables` as following

```
root, listFile[], uFiles, f1, f2, f3, f4,
```

pay attention as you may consider some directories have sub-directories but that not always the case, so you have to check that `listFiles()` is indeed returns the array of files otherwise you have to deal with more `bugs` in the `code`